# Can't Access NVIDIA Control Panel with PCIe Connected Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Motherboard: ASUS ROG Maximus IX Code

GPU: GeForce GTX 1660

CPU: Intel i7-7700K @ 4.2GHz

When I try to open the NVIDIA control panel I receive the following message: "NVIDIA Display settings are not available: You are not currently using a display attached to an NVIDIA GPU". The message is correct - my display is connected to the motherboard HDMI out. This is because the dedicated GPU is connected directly to the motherboard via PCIe and has no ports for direct connection to display. Since I cannot use the control panel, I cannot properly configure or monitor my GPU.

I have ruled out the following as problems:

- Driver issues
- BIOS GPU selection issues.

**EDIT**

So, it turns out newer GPUs have little plastic tags inserted into the ports...

You just have to remove them...

Wow. Just, wow.